# SteamVR plugin for Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I have downloaded the newest SteamVR plugin for Unity 2.0. But when using teleportation with teleportaionpoint i can't seem to make it change the scene.
Hoping someone can answer (:

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stackoverflow. In order for us to help you please share what you have tried so far, What was the expected output, And what went wrong with your code in a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and complete way.

Answer (score 0):

Yea had a bit trouble with that as well but managed to learn it from unity scene manager

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SwitchScene2 : MonoBehaviour
{

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }


}
```

This is the script that will be used for your scene just make sure you add the scenes to your scenes in Build by clicking Add open Scenes and making a trigger to allow you to go from one scene to the next. I just made a box collider door that will take you to a museum gallery. Hopefully that helps and good luck!